# Trying to process a JSON array that is received through POST method (Retrofit2)

Tags: android, arrays, json, post, retrofit2

Im having difficulty trying to parse a JSON array retrieved through POST method. I am very very new to this, please forgive me for any ignorance.

RequestInterface.java

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @POST("index.php/")
    Call<Classes> queryclass(@Body ServerRequest request);

}
```

Classes.java

```
public class Classes {

    @SerializedName("classname")
    private String classname;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    private String subject;
    @SerializedName("classday")
    private String classday;
    @SerializedName("timestart")
    private String timestart;
    @SerializedName("timeend")
    private String timeend;

    public Classes(String classname, String subject, String classday, String timestart, String timeend){

        this.classname = classname;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.classday = classday;
        this.timestart = timestart;
        this.timeend = timeend;

    }

    public String getClassname() {
        return classname;
    }
}
```

ServerRequest.java

```
public class ServerRequest {

private String queryclass;
private User user;

public void setQueryClass(String queryclass) { this.queryclass = queryclass; }

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

Activity (Retrofit)

```
User user = new User();
user.setEmail(email);
ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
request.setQueryClass(Constants.QUERYCLASSES_OPERATION);
request.setUser(user);
Call<Classes> response = requestInterface.queryclass(request);

response.enqueue(new Callback<Classes>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Classes> call, Response<Classes> response) {

        if(!response.isSuccessful()){
            tvData.setText(response.code());
            return;
        }

        Classes resp = response.body();

        String content = "";

        content += "code: " + response.code() + "\n";
        content += "classname: " + resp.getClassname() + "\n";

        tvData.setText(content);

    }

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Classes> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("TAG",t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    });
```

The JSON array I'm trying to show (Postman)

```
[
    {
        "classname": "PHYS1201",
        "subject": "PHYS12",
        "classday": "THU",
        "timestart": "18:00:00",
        "timeend": "20:00:00"
    },
    {
        "classname": "CHEM1202",
        "subject": "CHEM12",
        "classday": "FRI",
        "timestart": "12:00:00",
        "timeend": "14:00:00"
    }
]
```

It just shows "classname: null" when the app is running. Sorry about such a long and confusing post, any help would be appreciated.

---

**Clarification:** The POST request is sending an email(id) which returns an array of classes for that specific id. This works in postman, giving me the array shown above, but for some reason the response isn't recognised as an array by Retrofit. I have tried using *List* but it seems to recognise the response as an object, instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the list if you want to get a JSON array value.

like this :

```java
public interface RequestInterface {
    @POST("index.php/")
    Call<List<Classes>> queryclass(@Body ServerRequest request);
}
```

Comment: When I use a list, retrofit doesnt recognise the response and says "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but found BEGIN_OBJECT"